# C# user-input size of

Tags: c#, arrays, user-input

I want to be able to create an array with random integers where the size of it is the user's choice and I can transfer the printed out array into a different textbox.

i tried

```
        int listamount; //stores the number

        if (int.TryParse(LStextbox.Text, out listamount) && LStextbox.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            //int.tryparse converts the string into a integer
            //text.lentgh > 0 makes sure the box will not be left blank

        }
        else
        {

        }
        int min = 0;
        int max = 100; //i want to make the max an indefinite number, is that posible?

        int num = listamount;
        Random r = new Random();

        int[] ar;
        ar = new int[num];
        for (i = 0; int =< num - 1; i++)
        {
            ar[i] = r.Next(min, max);
        }
```

Comment: OK, you tried something, what happened?  Always include full error messages and expected vs actual results.

Comment: which error/unwanted behavior have you get? what did you expect and what you got?

Comment: You would take the max value from user input the same way as `listamount`, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: I'm writing my code in XAML and what my program needs to do is, first, get the user's input on the size list, then the press a button which will generate the array of random numbers with the size list of the user's choice and then i need the array to be printed out into a different textbox

Answer (score 0):

Ypu can use below approach:

You can achieve max int by using **Int32.MaxValue** statement.

By the way you have some mistakes with in the for loop, I have corrected them.

```
int listamount; //stores the number
if (int.TryParse(LStextbox.Text, out listamount) && LStextbox.Text.Length > 0)
{
    //int.tryparse converts the string into a integer
    //text.lentgh > 0 makes sure the box will not be left blank

}
else
{

}
int min = 0;
int max = Int32.MaxValue; //i want to make the max an indefinite number, is that posible?

int num = listamount;
Random r = new Random();

int[] ar;
ar = new int[num];
for (int i = 0; i <= num - 1; i++)
{
    ar[i] = r.Next(min, max);
}
foreach(int y in ar)
    Console.WriteLine(y);
```